# How to identify from a list of list which are the coordinates (x,y) that appear and plasm it into a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, coordinates

I have a list of lists with different coordinates of different images. I want to create a data frame with two columns: coordinates and value being value how many times we can find this pixel (this value has to be 0 if it's not found in the whole list or a concrete number if we can find it x times).
What I have done is this:

```
p = (0,0)
x = 0
y = 1
z = 0
d= {'Coordinates': [p], 'Value': [z]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
for _ in range(img.size[0]*img.size[1]-1):
    new_row = {"p":(x,y), "z":z}
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index = True)
    y = y+1
    if y = img.size[1]+1:
        y = 0
        x= x+1
print(df)
```

The pixels marked are in a list of lists and what should be changed from this code is the z value.
The data frame I want to get is something like:

[image: Data frame]

An exameple of the list of coordinates I have is:
[image: Coordinates]
Thanks for your help!! <3

Comment: I'm using pandas to create the data frame and pillow to import the images from where I got the list of list with different coordinates

Comment: Can you give an example of what the pixels in the lists of lists looks like? How are the pixels represented in the lists of lists?

Comment: The pixels are represented in a list like: [[(x,y),(x,y)...][(x,y),(x,y)...]...] and you can see and example in the foto I have attached. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter` to get all the unique pixels that have a count not equal to 0, then in order to add pixels that also have a count of 0, you can loop through all pixels (0,0)... (max_x, max_y) and compare their count to the Counter object.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
    
coordinates = [[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)],[(0,1),(0,2),(1,1)],[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]]
# this should return a value of 2 for (0,1),(0,2),(1,1)
# value of 1 for (0,3),(2,2),(3,3)
# values of 0 for all other pixels from (0,0)... (3,3) not in coordinates

# flatten the list of coordinates
all_coordinates = [item for img in coordinates for item in img]
c = Counter(all_coordinates)

# you want to look at the counts for pixels (0,0), ... (3,3) in c
max_x = max([item[0] for item in all_coordinates])
max_y = max([item[1] for item in all_coordinates])
coordinates_dict = dict()
for i in range(max_x + 1):
    for j in range(max_y + 1):
        coordinates_dict.update({(i,j): c[(i,j)]})

df = pd.DataFrame(coordinates_dict.items(), columns=['Coordinates','Value'])
```

---

Output:

```
>>> df
   Coordinates  Value
0       (0, 0)      0
1       (0, 1)      2
2       (0, 2)      2
3       (0, 3)      1
4       (1, 0)      0
5       (1, 1)      2
6       (1, 2)      0
7       (1, 3)      0
8       (2, 0)      0
9       (2, 1)      0
10      (2, 2)      1
11      (2, 3)      0
12      (3, 0)      0
13      (3, 1)      0
14      (3, 2)      0
15      (3, 3)      1
```

Comment: That was very useful, thanks, but how would you add into this list the coordinates that dont appear in the list (that would have a 0 value) so that I can create a heatmap later? I mean, I want to have in the column of coordinates the full list of coordinates of the pixels of a photo. If this photo is 1050*720, 756000 entries, most of them with the vaue of 0. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know if it's important or not to say this but in each list inside a list you won't find the same coordinates because each coordinate represents on pixel. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback – I'll get back to you on this! You should be able to fill in all of the missing values for the coordinates from (0,0) up to (1050,720)

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if this works for you~

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for your help. I don't know how to tell you how grateful I am.

Comment: No problem! Accepting the answer is already a great way to say thanks— and will help anyone with the same problem in future :)

Comment: Sorry @derek, how can I do to quit the y coordinate value from the list that don't exist from the dataframe?. I mean, if my original photo is 1050*525 (I said it wrong before), in the list appear values like (1049,1049) equaling 0. I think the dataframe considering coordinates that doesn't exist... I don't know if I expressed correctly... Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217423/discussion-between-derek-o-and-joan-carles-montero-jimenez).